# HTML links not clickable? (tried and tried, can't find any reason)

Tags: html, hyperlink

I am definitely a novice at HTML, CSS, and Javascript but for this webpage, some links are clickable and others are not. I read about inline and block elements and maybe I am missing something but I can't figure out what I'm doing incorrectly here. These aren't the real links but you get the general idea. The last two links within the  tags work, but the first four do not. Below is the problem I believe, but I will also include the rest of the html after the first snippet.

```html
<body>
   <p>| <a href="http://www.google.com">Exploring Computer Science</a> |
      | <a href="http://www.google.com">Computer Programming I</a> |
      | <a href="http://www.google.com">Computer Programming II</a> |</p>

 <p>
     Students in the computer science major will study the design and operation of computer hardware and software by developing problem-solving skills and the   ability      to apply computational thinking to real-world problems. Focusing on programming and coding, ‘app’ and website development, robotics, cyber security, computer      forensics and geographic information systems, students 
     will be prepared for further study and the fast-paced world of 
     technology. Work-based learning through mentoring, field trips 
     and internships will allow students to showcase their education while gaining valuable experience. Participation in the Technology Student Association is      encouraged.</p>


 <p> A major at <a href="http://www.google.com">schoolname</a></p>

 <br/>

 

 <img src="http://oi61.tinypic.com/2ip27b.jpg" align="middle" />


   <br/><br/> 

 <span style="font-size:12px">Javascript code for animation provided by <a href="http://www.codeacademy.com">codeacademy</a> with the help of Google, Rob  Hawkes, and  Mark Brenig-Jones & Emile Petrone. <a href="http://www.tattoocanyon.com/97-yin-yang-tattoos/2460-yin-yang-koi-tattoo-by-tsukiohkami-design-art- flash/">Koi  design</a> image source. </span>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<header>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/hour-of-code/js/alphabet.js"></script>

  <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="bubbles.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>


 <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text.css" />


</header>
  
</head>
<body>
   <p>| <a href="http://www.google.com">Exploring Computer Science</a> |
   | <a href="http://www.google.com">Computer Programming I</a> |
   | <a href="http://www.google.com">Computer Programming II</a> |</p>

 <p>
     Students in the computer science major will study the design and operation of computer hardware and software by developing problem-solving skills and the   ability      to apply computational thinking to real-world problems. Focusing on programming and coding, ‘app’ and website development, robotics, cyber security, computer      forensics and geographic information systems, students 
     will be prepared for further study and the fast-paced world of 
     technology. Work-based learning through mentoring, field trips 
     and internships will allow students to showcase their education while gaining valuable experience. Participation in the Technology Student Association is      encouraged.</p>


 <p> A major at <a href="http://www.google.com">schoolname</a></p>

 <br/>

 

 <img src="http://oi61.tinypic.com/2ip27b.jpg" align="middle" />


   <br/><br/> 

 <span style="font-size:12px">Javascript code for animation provided by <a href="http://www.codeacademy.com">codeacademy</a> with the help of Google, Rob  Hawkes, and  Mark Brenig-Jones & Emile Petrone. <a href="http://www.tattoocanyon.com/97-yin-yang-tattoos/2460-yin-yang-koi-tattoo-by-tsukiohkami-design-art- flash/">Koi  design</a> image source. </span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: They all seem to work okay in this context. What are they not doing that they should be?

Comment: The first four links simply appear as text; they're not clickable. The last two where I'm giving source info work fine. I can't figure out why they won't work as links. @StuartMiller

Comment: The four that all point to Google? They seem to work okay for me when I run the code snippet on here.

Comment: @StuartMiller it was a weird issue but I re-positioned some things and now they work fine! Thanks for the help.

Comment: I was thinking that perhaps there was an invisible element positioned over the top of them that was stopping them being clickable. Glad you sorted it!